How to implement JWT authentication insted of cookie in dot-net-core-8?
Is it possible to have only jwt authentication instead of cookie auth and how in dot-net-core 8 ?

may I understand the issue as that the server API is configured well now as when we test the api with swagger it could generate the token and use it to call the API successfully, but the issue only occurred in the .net 8 client app after it's not using cookie authentication? If so, maybe this ticket could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74234664/may-i-implement-identity-server-4-authentification-with-jwt-token-and-mvc-client

By the way, could you pls help confirm whether your client app could obtain the access token? Or could you pls test your client to use the token you get from swagger(manually add request header Authorization: Bearer access_token) to call the secured API? Using codes like const response = await fetch('https://yourapi/endpoint', {  method: 'GET', headers: {'Authorization': Bearer ${token}} });  My idea is that, let's make sure the API is working well now and we are able to obtain the token and use the token to call API, then let's use the token in client APP to call the API.

Yes, although how is a bit broad and would depend on a few things. Make an attempt to implement it and then ask another question if/when you get stuck.
